# How to select and then delete cell in TStringGrid in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I know how to enter data into grid, but I need to make also delete button for selected rows. I've been looking threw internet, found almost nothing. how to delete thing, i just cant find anywere how to select specific cell and then, how to edit/delete or do anything with her.
Here is example what I mean by that:

I select by mouse or anything 1 cell, then it selects (for example) whole row in which this cell was. After that I click button delete. How to tell delete function which row was selected.

Comment: You cant delete individual cells, but you can edit/clear their content by using the `TStringGrid.Cells` property, eg: `StringGrid1.Cells[Col, Row] := '';`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your anwser. I know I can delete rows/cols. All i need is information how to SELECT in code.
. How to do anything with selected cell/row. For example, you click on cell [1,2] and then you want to delete her. You click button delete and done. How delete command knows, which cell i want to delete. I hope i made it more clear.

Comment: "*How delete command knows, which cell i want to delete*" - Use the `TStringGrid.Col` and `TStringGrid.Row` properties to get/set the currently selected cell, eg: `StringGrid1.Cells[StringGrid1.Col, StringGrid1.Row] := '';` Also have a look at the `TStringGrid.Selection` property for selecting a range of cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an anwser:

Create procedure:

```
procedure StringGridDeleteRow( AStringGrid:TStringGrid; ARow:integer );
var
  nRow:integer;
begin
  with AStringGrid do
    begin
      for nRow := ARow to RowCount - 2 do
        Rows[nRow].Assign(Rows[nRow+1]);
      Rows[RowCount-1].Clear;
      RowCount := RowCount - 1
    end;
end;
```

and then add this line to your button:

```
StringGridDeleteRow(StringGrid1, StringGrid1.Row);
```

It was easier than I thought!

Comment: You don't need to call Clear, you can remove that line.

Comment: What about using ``BeginUpdate/EndUpdate``?

Comment: You can create a class helper for StringGrid. Then you will be able to do `StringGrid1.DeleteRow(i)` and move this part of code from your form to a separate unit